# jqgrid reloadGrid event listener

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

Im using jqgrid and i am triggring `reloadGrid` upon some events.

I just want to handle the `reloadGrid` event so that i am able to get the `userData` from the reloaded one. 
For this you might suggest me to use `loadComplete` but `loadComplete` is called event on first load of grid. But i want to listen only the `reloadGrid` event.

I tried the following but cannot achieve what i wanted.

```
if($('#table').trigger('reloadGrid').length>0)
{
var userData = $('#table').jqgrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
//here the userData is old data not the reloaded one.
}
```

Can anyone suggest me any work around.

Comment: What you want with `$('#table').trigger('reloadGrid').length>0`? The first part of the code (`$('#table').trigger('reloadGrid')`) trigger the reload. Which `length` you want test? Do you want to set `userData` before or after reloading? Do you want to set `userData` only if it will be triggered **by your own code** or you want do the same on any `reloadGrid` event (for example on sorting or paging or data)?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this :

```
// to trigger the event
$('#table').trigger('reloadGrid');  

// to listen to the event
$('#table').on('reloadGrid', function() {
   var userData = $('#table').jqgrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
   //here the userData is old data not the reloaded one.
})
```

You trigger the event using `.trigger()` and listen to the event using `.on()` ... [docs for `.on()` here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @Sandeep: The posted code is correct and it answers on the question which you asked, but your answer with `loadComplete` shows that you need *not what you asked*. The `loadComplete` will be called not only in case of `trigger('reloadGrid')`. Moreover even if you call `trigger('reloadGrid')` explicitly the `loadComplete` can be not called. Instead of that `loadError` can be called for example or the processing can be stopped by returning `false` from `beforeProcessing`. In any way **the text of your question not corresponds to what you really want to have**.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks ... not really sure the OP understands what they want or what they are doing ....

Comment: @ManseUK: You are right! By the way jqGrid has some other events: "jqGridLoadComplete" and "jqGridAfterLoadComplete" which will be triggered before and after calling of `loadComplete` callback, but the main problem is probably that Sandeep really not sure what he really want or need.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a work around for that.

Had a global variable as

```
var loadedonce = false;
```

And in the `loadComplete` listener the following is done.

```
loadComplete: function(data){
if(!loadedonce){
//some manupulations
loadedonce = true;
}
else{
var userData = $('#table').jqgrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
//this userData has the latest data i needed
}
}
```

If anyone has much better workaround please do share...

Comment: It is **very bad to spend the time of other people** with asking the question if you want just post your own answer! You post the question which can be interpreted in many cases, and post his own answer with some interpretation of your question. Such question and the answer have some value only for you and not for other reader.